# Error "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature." when importing Esri types

Tags: typescript, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I feel like there is something really simple that I am missing here. I've got a class that I am building out that uses Esri ArcGIS API, but when I import the type definitions from the `arcgis-js-api`'s `d.ts` file, I get the typescript error "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."

Ex:

```
import * as IMap from 'esri/Map';

export class Foo {
    bar: (Map: IMap) {
        const map = new Map(); // <-- error here
    }
}
```

relevant snippets from the `d.ts` file:

```
declare namespace __esri {
    /* snip */
    interface Map extends Accessor, LayersMixin {
        allLayers: Collection;
        basemap: Basemap;
        ground: Ground;
    }

    interface MapConstructor {
        new(properties?: MapProperties): Map;
    }

    export const Map: MapConstructor;
    /* snip */
}

declare module "esri/Map" {
    import Map = __esri.Map;
    export = Map;
}
```

Looks like the type definition is correct to me, so what am I doing wrong that would make Typescript think that the `IMap` type doesn't have a constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Map` in your parameter is an instance of the `IMap` type. If you wanted to type it as the constructor instead, type it as `typeof IMap`:

```
bar (Map: typeof IMap) {
    const map = new Map(); 
}
```