# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined after creating a model

Tags: angular, angular6

I am very new to angular. I define a model that export some fields. Before I had all the object of user written in my ts file. Now after I create model I am getting error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

How can I fix this error?

These are my codes.

### user.model.ts

```
export class User {
    name: string = '';
    email: string = '';
    password: any = '';
}
```

### register.component.ts

```
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    public form: User;
}
```

### register.html

```
<form #signupForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="form.name" class="form-control" id="inputname3" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
```

Comment: where did u set up the `form`  object

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the User ,

```
 public form: User;

constructor(){
  this.form = new User();
}
```

Comment: error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Comment: @user1687891 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990638/error-cannot-use-new-with-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-or-construct

Answer (score 1):

> register.component.ts

```
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
   public form: User = {};
}
```

**Please try this.**

Comment: I get this error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to
type 'User'.

Comment: "export interface  User {
    name: string,
    email: string,
    password:any,
}"

please try this user.model.ts

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is create an `interface` `UserRef` for type checking

**user.ts**

```
export interface UserRef {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: any;
}
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { UserRef } from '../../contracts/user';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    public form: FormGroup;
    public user: UserRef;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.user = new User()
       // form setup
       // this.form = ...

    }
}
```

**user.model.ts** should look like

```
export class User {
    name: string = '';
    email: string = '';
    password: any = '';
    constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your `form` object before you use it.

Working copy is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xn211g